# Elastic Search Master not discovered Exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not able to setup elastic server cluster as I am getting **"Master not discovered exception"**

My configuration are

**Master**

```
node.master:true
node.data:true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip of master"]
tcp.port:9300
```

**Client**

```
node.master:false
node.data:true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ip of master:9300"]
```

when we are hitting **curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/master?v'**  from client it is showing **master not discovered exception**.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Logs

elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
    Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-02-19 07:44:33 EST; 2min 35s ago
   Docs: http://www.elastic.co
    Process: 25531 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 25535 (java)
  CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
          └─25535 /bin/java -Xms8g -Xmx8g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFra...

Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: [2016-02-19 07:46:49,471][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /_aliases Para...iases}
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: MasterNotDiscoveredException[null]
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$Async...a:205)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateList...a:239)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout....a:794)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Feb 19 07:46:49 centos-16gb-sgp1-01 elasticsearch[25535]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

There is java version mismatch on both the machines, so after fixing version problem and client happily joined the cluster